# Modify a DBF file

Tags: python

I want to modify one column in a .dpf file using Python with this library http://pythonhosted.org/dbf/. 
When I want to print out some column, it works just fine. But when I am trying to modify a column, I get error

> unable to modify fields individually except in `with` or `Process()`

My code:

```
table = dbf.Table('./path/to/file.dbf')
table.open()

for record in table:
    record.izo = sys.argv[2]

table.close()
```

In docs, they recommend doing it like

```
for record in Write(table):
```

But I also get an error:

> name 'Write' is not defined
>   And:

```
record.write_record(column=sys.argv[2])
```

Also gives me an error that

> write_record - no such field in table

Thanks!

Comment: `d(B)f` or `d(P)f`? You're using BOTH all over your question

Comment: How did you imported the dbf module? Probably you need to use dbf.Write(table)

Comment: I've imported it using import dbf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies for the state of the docs.  Here are a couple options that should work:

```
table = dbf.Table('./path/to/file.dbf')
# Process will open and close a table if not already opened
for record in dbf.Process(table):
    record.izo = sys.argv[2]
```

or

```
with dbf.Table('./path/to/file.dbf')
    # with opens a table, closes when done
    for record in table:
        with record:
            record.izo = sys.argv[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to make a change to my dbf file for several days and searched and browsed several websites, this page was the only one that gave me a solution that worked. Just to add a little more information so that whoever lands here would understand the above piece of code that Ethan Furman shared.

```
import dbf
table = dbf.Table('your_dbf_filename.dbf')
# Process will open and close a table if not already opened
for record in dbf.Process(table):
    record.your_column_name = 'New_Value_of_that_column'
```

Now, because you don't have a condition mentioned here, you would end you updating all the rows of your column. Remember, this statement will immediately reflect the new value in that column. So, the advice is to save a copy of this dbf file before making any edits to it.
I also tried the 2nd solution that Ethan mentions, but it throws an error that 'table' not defined.