# Dbf file modification script

Tags: php, python, dbf

I'm trying to create a script which takes a .dbf file modifies one column in it.
I tried to do it with Python and library called `dbf` but it didn't work ([Modify a DBF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000886/modify-a-dbf-file)).
Then I tried a PHP and `dBase` but because I'm using PHP7, I've installed this https://github.com/mote0230/dbase-pecl-php7, but when I was trying to call `dbase_replace_record` or `dbase_add_record`, I always get `__Abort trap: 6__`.

```
$pathToDbf = $pathToUnzip . '/path/to/dbf/file.dbf';
$dbf = dbase_open($pathToDbf, 2);

if ( $dbf ) {
    $headers = dbase_get_header_info($dbf);
    $recordNumbers = dbase_numrecords($dbf);


    $row = dbase_get_record_with_names($dbf, 1);
    $newRecords = [];
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $newRecords[] = $value;
    }
    $add = dbase_add_record($dbf, $newRecords);
}
```

Same thing with `dbase_replace_record`.
The problem with using version of PHP < 7 is that people who will use this script works with PHP7 and it is not practical for them to switch to PHP5.6
So my question is, what should I use in order to create my script? Would you pick different programming language or library?
**Thanks!**

Comment: please see: How to modify dbf files in Python
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462771/how-to-modify-dbf-files-in-python